# Testing 3-way interaction of categorical variables in a meta analysis in R

Tags: r, interaction, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I'm currently working on a meta-analysis using the metafor package for R. I have several categorical moderators, a few of which are multi-category, that I'm including in the analyses. When using one moderator at a time, interpretation of results is easy as the results for the referent group are represented by the intercept value (the categorical variables are dummy coded). This is all fine.

The challenge I'm having is that I'm trying to determine whether or not a 3-way interaction exists, but because of the dummy coding I can't get estimates for the values and confidence intervals of the interaction that includes the reference group. This is an issue because I a) want to know what the influence of this 3-way interaction is and b) I'll be expected to report those statistics in a publication.

Does anyone have any advice? I've thought about subsetting the data along one of the moderators (research method: laboratory or field), but I don't think that answers the question of whether or not the interaction of two moderators has an influence on the overall average effect size.

I appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: It is worth noting here that nothing about this is R-specific.

Comment: the package is specific to R which was the reason for the tag

Comment: Two comments: 1) Is this helpful? http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions and 2) In the end, this isn't even meta-analysis or `metafor` specific -- it is about working with linear models and interpreting interactions. So, whatever you would do if you had a 'regular' dataset (for a single study) with three categorical predictors, you can do in the context of a 'meta-regression'.

Comment: I find three way interactions very hard to explain and one strategy which sometimes illuminates things is to combine the factors into a single factor so that instead of 2 by 2 by 2 you have a single 8 level factor. Sometimes it is easier to see what is going on but your mileage may vary.